# How to raise PBO on previous modal dialog?

Tags: abap

I have two dialogs, that one call another. To clarify what I mean, let's take a look at the first dialog:

[image]

As you can see on the screen, it contains ALV. When I click on the row, it will open the second dialog:
[image]

When I close the second dialog, I want to trigger PBO on the first is screen to do rerender ALV. How to archive it?

**Update**
Code, that call the second screen:

```
  METHOD handle_double_click.

    FIELD-SYMBOLS <lt_task> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <ls_task> TYPE any.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <ls_clicked_data> TYPE any.

    DATA(lo_task_provider) = lcl_alv_task_provider=>get_instance( ).
    DATA(lt_task) = lo_task_provider->c_gt_data.

    ASSIGN lt_task->* TO <lt_task>.

    IF sy-subrc <> 0 OR <lt_task>[] IS INITIAL.
      RETURN.
    ENDIF.

    CREATE DATA lo_task_provider->c_gs_clicked_data LIKE LINE OF <lt_task>.
    ASSIGN lo_task_provider->c_gs_clicked_data->* TO <ls_clicked_data>.

    READ TABLE <lt_task> ASSIGNING <ls_task> INDEX e_row.
    <ls_clicked_data> = <ls_task>.

    zdp2_planning_split = me->fill_splitt_info( <ls_task> ).

    DATA(ls_planning_split_alv) = VALUE zdp2_planning_split_alv( matnr = zdp2_planning_split-matnr
                                                                 lfdat = zdp2_planning_split-lfdat
                                                                 sollmng = zdp2_planning_split-sollmng
                                                                 meins = zdp2_planning_split-meins ).
    DATA(lt_planning_split_alv) = VALUE zdp2_planning_split_alv_t( ).
    INSERT ls_planning_split_alv INTO TABLE lt_planning_split_alv.

    lcl_alv_split_provider=>get_instance( )->insert_data( lt_planning_split_alv ).

    CALL SCREEN '0100' STARTING AT 8 8.

  ENDMETHOD.
```

**Update**

I think the pictures do not clarify what I mean. Now this should be better:

[image]

The first modal call the second modal. When the second modal get closed, then the ALV on the first screen should be refreshed. I can't refresh it, because the PBO on the first screen does not get executed after the second modal get closed.

Comment: Is the second dialog replace the first? Could you please attach the code that navigates from the first to the second?

Comment: The first does not replace the second dialog. I posted the code, where the second screen get called.

Comment: Question also asked on SCN : https://answers.sap.com/questions/722555/how-to-raise-pbo-on-previous-modal-dialog.html

Comment: @zero_coding your latest update (Jan 8 at 14:22) reflects what I understood initially. **Cf my answer** (the PBO is not called but you can still update the alv grid; if you really want your pbo to be called then you can force the PAI/PBO to be triggered)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the method `HANDLE_DOUBLE_CLICK` is triggered on event `DOUBLE_CLICK` of `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`. This event only triggers a method, it doesn't start the PAI (consequently the PBO is not triggered too).

If you want to trigger the PAI, just add this line (you have to indicate a function code, here "ZZZ") :

```
cl_gui_cfw=>set_new_ok_code( new_code = 'ZZZ' ).
```

But instead, after `CALL SCREEN`, why don't you just **refresh** the ALV grid.

Assuming that you programmed the ALV grid with class `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`, add this code :

```
" first update the internal table of the ALV
...

" transfer the internal table to the control, it also does an "update_view"
alv_grid->refresh_table_display( ).
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use CALL SCREEN '0100' STARTING AT 8 8.

Following is the sample code to call popup screen, when popup screen is close then you can write code to refresh first ALV screen data.

```
  TYPES: BEGIN OF alv_line,
             carrid   TYPE spfli-carrid,
             connid   TYPE spfli-connid,
             cityfrom TYPE spfli-cityfrom,
             cityto   TYPE spfli-cityto,
           END OF alv_line.
    DATA   alv_tab    TYPE TABLE OF alv_line.
    SELECT carrid, connid, cityfrom, cityto
           FROM spfli
           WHERE carrid = @carrid
           INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @alv_tab.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE e007(sabapdemos).
    ENDIF.
    TRY.
        cl_salv_table=>factory(
          IMPORTING r_salv_table = DATA(alv)
          CHANGING  t_table = alv_tab ).
        alv->set_screen_popup( start_column = 1
                               end_column   = 60
                               start_line   = 1
                               end_line     = 12 ).
        alv->display( ).
      CATCH cx_salv_msg.
        MESSAGE 'ALV display not possible' TYPE 'I'
                DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
    ENDTRY.
```